# HTML 5 Canvas Mouse over event on element (show tooltip)

Tags: html5-canvas, mouseevent, kineticjs

I am working on a visualization project. Based on my data I am plotting hundreds of small circle on canvas. I want to add a mouse over event so that whenever a mouse is the enclosing area of a circle it will show some node property from my data as a tool tip or as text on the canvas.
My current drawCircle method

```
function drawCircle(canvas,x,y,r) 
{
    canvas.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    canvas.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
    canvas.lineWidth = 2;
    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    canvas.stroke();
    canvas.fill();
    canvas.closePath();
}
```

I have looked into [kinetic.js](http://www.kineticjs.com/)
But can't figure it out how I can call my drawCircle [repetitively] method using their library.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still want to use KineticJS, you would put the Kinetic shape stuff inside your drawCircle routine.  This is basically pulled out of [their tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/) and stripped down:

```
function drawCircle(stage,x,y,r) {
  var circle = new Kinetic.Shape(function(){
    var context = this.getContext();
    // draw the circle here: strokeStyle, beginPath, arc, etc...
  });
  circle.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    // do something
  });
  stage.add(circle);
}
```

If you don't want to use KineticJS after all, you will need to remember for yourself the positions and radii of every circle you drew, and then do something like this:

```
canvas.onmouseover = function onMouseover(e) {
  var mx = e.clientX - canvas.clientLeft;
  var my = e.clientY - canvas.clientTop;
  // for each circle...
  if ((mx-cx)*(mx-cx)+(my-cy)*(my-cy) < cr*cr)
    // the mouse is over that circle
}
```

Comment: hi, cx is radius x? and cy raidus y?, and what is cr?, thanks

Comment: (cx, cy) are the coordinates of the center of the circle, and cr is the radius of the circle.